# Leaked Daesh (ISIS) Documents

Tags: leak, terrorism

This: [dailymail - Names and family details of 22000 jihadis revealed by huge cache of leaked ISIS HR-forms](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3484702/Names-family-details-22-000-jihadis-revealed-huge-cache-leaked-ISIS-HR-forms.html). Of course, whether the names of family details should be published is debatable. But the other variables seem to be less sensitive and could potentially be made public.

Are they or a subset of variables available somewhere?

If not, who would one have to approach to get an (anonymized) version of the data?

Comment: The data was leaked on a USB stick to some Syrian opposition media which then shared a portion with German intelligence and Sky News. So for the moment it's probably not downloadable. Source: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DbSUVAT36zQJ:www.wired.com/2016/03/hack-brief-isis-data-breach-identifies-22000-members/+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=ch

Comment: Are there any news on this?